# Add pattern to regex for German house number system

Tags: python, regex

I have a Python regex for German house numbers which works okay. However, some pattern doesn't match as you can see in this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aVhlYS/1).

These should be valid:

- 56/58a
- 18a - 19b
- 18a-19b

This should not be valid (because the number of digits is too long):

- 12345

This is my regex:
`^[1-9]\d*(?: ?(?:[a-zA-Z]|[/-] ?\d+[a-z]?))?$`

Comment: There is a space after `56/58a` in your regex fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^[1-9]\d{0,3} ?[a-zA-Z]?(?: ?[/-] ?[1-9]\d{0,3} ?[a-zA-Z]?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p8Vpl8/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[1-9]\d{0,3} ?[a-zA-Z]?` - a non-zero digit, then zero to three digits, then an optional space and then an optional letter
- `(?: ?[/-] ?[1-9]\d{0,3} ?[a-zA-Z]?)?` - an optional sequence of an optional space, `/` or `-`, an optional space and, like the part explained above, a non-zero digit, then zero to three digits, then an optional space and then an optional letter
- `$` - end of string.